# Android Studio ClipArt does'nt show any icons

Tags: android, android-studio

The Select icon dialog box doesn't show any icons

[image]

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you can add an explicit question about what you are trying to solve for others to understand it clearly and help you! For example; "How can I make the left window icon to appear on Android Studio?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of `android-studio`